# Is there a way to pass sobject record from html to lwc on radio button change

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightninginput, radio-button

I am displaying list of contacts in table in lwc. I have a radio button placed in each row of the table. On clicking that, I'm able to send the contact record id but I want to send that particular contact record itself. I'm getting empty value when I tried to do that.

```
<template for:each={records} for:item='conItem'>
            <tr key={conItem}>
                <td><lightning-input type="radio" name="radioButtonSelect1" value={conItem} onchange={handleChangeRadio}></lightning-input></td>
                <td>{conItem.FirstName}</td>
                <td>{conItem.LastName}</td>
                <td>{conItem.Email}</td>
                <td>{conItem.Phone}</td>
            </tr>
 </template>

handleChangeRadio(event){        
    this.contactId = event.target.value;
    console.log('=====contactRec==='+this.contactId);//coming as empty value
}
```

Comment: Hello sfdcPal, have you tried to use `value={conItem.Id}` instead of `value={conItem}` on the radio input_

Comment: My Bad !!! I just edited my question. I was able to send contact id when using value={conItem.Id}. But I want to send {conItem} itself

Comment: The recommendation is to use primitive values, the same recommendation as found on [Create and Dispatch Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch). So, I would recommend getting the Id and, querying the data if needed.

Comment: Ok got it !! Thanks for the doc reference